# Cannot configure network on ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I have a desktop running ubuntu server(without GUI) on which i want to configure the internet settings. I can connect to internet via same lan port using windows or GUI based linux desktop with dhcp settings but could not do so on my server. Please address the problem along with the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Ethernet Interfaces**

Ethernet interfaces are identified by the system using the naming convention of ethX, where X represents a numeric value. The first Ethernet interface is typically identified as eth0, the second as eth1, and all others should move up in numerical order.

- Identify Ethernet Interfaces

An application that can help identify all network interfaces available to your system is the `lshw` command. In the example below, lshw shows a single Ethernet interface with the logical name of eth0 along with bus information, driver details and all supported capabilities.

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a
       size: 10MB/s
       capacity: 100MB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: (snipped for brevity)
       configuration: (snipped for brevity)
       resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
```

**Dynamic IP Address Assignment (DHCP Client)**

To configure your server to use DHCP for dynamic address assignment, add the dhcp method to the inet address family statement for the appropriate interface in the file */etc/network/interfaces*. The example below assumes you are configuring your first Ethernet interface identified as eth0.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

By adding an interface configuration as shown above, you can manually enable the interface through the ifup command which initiates the DHCP process via dhclient.

`sudo ifup eth0`

To manually disable the interface, you can use the ifdown command, which in turn will initiate the DHCP release process and shut down the interface.

`sudo ifdown eth0`

**Static IP Address Assignment**

To configure your system to use a static IP address assignment, add the static method to the inet address family statement for the appropriate interface in the file /etc/network/interfaces. The example below assumes you are configuring your first Ethernet interface identified as eth0. Change the address, netmask, and gateway values to meet the requirements of your network.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

After all this, please restart your networking service,

`sudo service networking restart`
For more information: [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, see, do you ubuntu recognize your network card.
Enough is to run command

```
ifconfig | grep eth
```

Is server see card output will be similar

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ ifconfig | grep eth
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:2c:4a:03:a1:46
```

To configure DHCP address you need to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` and you need to enter the following lines replace eth0 with your network interface card

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change configuration of `eth0` to:

```
# The primary network interface -- use DHCP to find our address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```